How to Resolve Oracle APEX Upgrade Error on Docker?
I'm trying to upgrade Oracle APEX from version 23.2 to 24.1 on a Docker setup with Oracle DB 23c and ORDS 24. During the upgrade, I encountered an error message: "There is a problem with your environment because the Oracle APEX files are not up-to-date! The files for version 23.2.0 have been loaded, but 24.1.0 is expected. Please verify that you have copied the images directory to your application server as instructed in the Installation Guide." I am looking for a solution to resolve this issue and successfully complete the upgrade.
installed Oracle DB 23c and ORDS 24 on Docker, which automatically installed Oracle APEX 23.2. I followed the upgrade steps to upgrade APEX from 23.2 to 24.1 as per the official documentation. I expected the upgrade to complete successfully, but I encountered an error stating that the APEX files are not up-to-date and that the files for version 23.2.0 have been loaded, but 24.1.0 is expected. I ensured that I copied the images directory to the application server as instructed, but the issue persists.

If you have some code you used you can post it to the Stack Overflow forum here so someone can help you.  If you don't have any code, you probably clicked the wrong Stack for this type of question.  Either update the question or move it to the proper stack, good luck!  Perhaps even Oracle has some support docs to help you with your error?
